# Images Display in emulator but not in real device?

Tags: java, android

When i put this url http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg, it display the image in all device device as well as in emulator. but when i put this url https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net//hprofile-ak-xfa1//t1.0-1//p50x50//10253981_10152392333247380_3365639944748198693_t.jpg, it display image in emulator but not in real device in android. why?

Please Help Me.

Comment: Start by posting the code you're using to download and display

Answer (score 0):

possible reason can be use of '//'. only after https: '//' is needed, however in your url at other places too '//' are being used.

https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net//hprofile-ak-xfa1//t1.0-1//p50x50//10253981_10152392333247380_3365639944748198693_t.jpg